# How to use Hamcrest to inspect Map items

Tags: junit, hamcrest

I have been recently using Hamcrest library to write some tests and quite successful but now I need to do something more complex and started to see a lot of difficulties. I need to inpsect and verify the properties of the items in a Map. My production code looks something like this:

```
    Map<String, List<MyItem>> map = new HashMap<String, List<MyItem>>();
    map.put("one", Arrays.asList(new MyItem("One")));
    map.put("two",  Arrays.asList(new MyItem("Two")));
    map.put("three",  Arrays.asList(new MyItem("Three")));
```

I want to write some test codes like the following, but it doesn't compile. Looks like Hamcrest's hasEntry is type-parametered, while hasItem and hasProperty only expect Object.

```
    assertThat(map, Matchers.<String, List<MyItem>>hasEntry("one",  hasItem(hasProperty("name", is("One")))));
```

My IDE (Eclipse) is giving this error message: The parameterized method `<String, List<HamcrestTest.MyItem>>hasEntry(String, List<HamcrestTest.MyItem>)` of type `Matchers` is not applicable for the arguments `(String, Matcher<Iterable<? super Object>>)`. For one thing I think Eclipse is confused of which `hasEntry` method I wanted to use, it should be `hasEntry(org.hamcrest.Matcher<? super K> keyMatcher, org.hamcrest.Matcher<? super V> valueMatcher)` , not the `hasEntry(K key, V value)`.

Should I just give up and get the item from the Map and manually inspect each property? Is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Youu could just use `contains` or `containsInAnyOrder`. True, you'll have to list all items in the `List` that way, but it works cleaner than `hasItem`:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Test
public void mapTest() {
  Map<String, List<MyItem>> map = new HashMap<String, List<MyItem>>();
  map.put("one", asList(new MyItem("1"), new MyItem("one")));

  assertThat(map, hasEntry(is("one"),
                           containsInAnyOrder(hasProperty("name", is("one")),
                                              hasProperty("name", is("1")))));
}
```

Comment: I don't believe this will resolve the compile-time error because the `hasEntry` will return a `Matcher<String, Iterable<Object>>` instead of the required `Matcher<String, List<MyItem>>`

Comment: @JohnB: Believe it or not, but I tried it and it works just peachy for me.

Comment: Should it work also for map with values of different type (`Map<String, Object>` to say it in java)?  
Because I'm trying it with mockito, and I have an `Overload resolution failed` compile error.

Answer (score 7):

Since @t0mppa didn't provide a good example on how to use Hamcrest's `contains` and `containsInAnyOrder` for this, here's a little something to get your started:

```
Map<Integer, String> columns = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
columns.put(1, "ID");
columns.put(2, "Title");
columns.put(3, "Description");

assertThat(columns.values(), contains("ID", "Title", "Description")); // passes
assertThat(columns.values(), contains("ID", "Description", "Title")); // fails
assertThat(columns.values(), containsInAnyOrder("ID", "Description", "Title")); // passes
```

Note that as opposed to `hasItem` and `hasItems`, these will only work if you provide them with a full list of all the values you'll be matching against. See Hamcrest's [javadocs](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#contains(E...)) for more information.

Comment: What is the import statements for contains?

Comment: @JeffCook: Almost every Hamcrest matcher can/should be imported via `org.hamcrest.Matchers.<matcherName>`.

Answer (score 6):

So just to make this simpler you might try this...

```
assertThat((Object)map, (Matcher)Matchers.hasEntry("one",  hasItem(hasProperty("name", is("One")))));
```

by going to a raw type you will get a warning but no compile error. If have used this trick in the past when I don't want to worry about getting all the casting just right for the compiler.

Also, you might consider using `ItIterableContainingInOrder.containingInOrder(new MyItem("One")))`. This will verify the entire list and if `MyItem` implements `equals` then you won't be using reflection in your tests.

Answer (score 0):

the `hasEntry` method has two signatures:

- `hasEntry(key, value)`
- `hasEntry(matcher<key>, matcher<value>)`

You are using the first signature, thus you are checking whether your map contains a matcher mapped to the string "one". [t0mppa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20198582/4844216) is using the second signature, that's why it works. The good news is you don't need to list all the elements in the list, you can just

```
assertThat(map, hasEntry(is("one"), hasItem(hasProperty("name", is("One")))));
```